# Click event RecyclerView doesn't works (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have recycler view

I need to open activity by click on element on recycler view

I do it like this in Adapter

```
  public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        var layout = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.MovieRow, parent, false);

        return new MovieViewHolder(layout, OnItemClick);

    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return movies.Count; }
    }

    void OnItemClick(int position)
    {
        if (ItemClick != null)

          // _context.StartActivity(typeof(Register));

           ItemClick(this, position);
    }
```

And like this on ViewHolder

```
 public MovieViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener) : base(itemView)
    {
        MovieNameTextView = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.movieNameText);
        DirectedByTextView = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.directedByText);
        Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image);
        itemView.Click += (s, e) => listener(Position);

    }
```

But when I click on element in Recycler View , nothing happens, where is my problem?

Comment: What are you doing with the `ItemClick` event in the Activity that is creating this RecyclerView ?

Comment: Can you share your full code? via github or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you do with your `ItemClick` and how you propagate it up to the surface.

So first of all, in your `MovieViewHolder` you want add an `EventHandler` to your item view's `Click` event, just like you've shown. You should also remember to remove the event subscription again, preferably in `Dispose` so that you don't leak memory.

So something like:

```
public MovieViewHolder(View itemView, ...) : base(itemView)
{
    ItemView.Click += OnItemClick;
}

private void OnItemClick(object s, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        ItemView.Click -= OnItemClick;
    }
}
```

Then I'd probably just use `ICommand` like most MVVM frameworks do, to propagate actions.

```
public ICommand ItemClick
{
    get; set;
}
```

Then in `OnItemClick` invoke the command:

```
private void OnItemClick(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ItemClick == null) return;
    if (ItemClick.CanExecute(null))
        ItemClick.Execute(null);
}
```

Then in your `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation you would assign the command in `OnCreateViewHolder`:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    var vh = new MovieViewHolder(...)
    {
        Click = ItemClick
    };

    return vh;
}
```

Your Adapter would also have a `ItemClick` `ICommand` property which you set from your View where you create it.

```
public ICommand ItemClick {get; set;}
```

In your View:

```
var recycler = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(...);
var adapter = new MovieAdapter {
    ItemClick = ViewModel.ItemClick
};
```

`ViewModel.ItemClick` here is just an instance of your implementation of `ICommand`. If you wan't you can change `ICommand` to `Action` instead or something like that to get a callback instead.

Just keep in mind, if you change the `MovieAdapter.ItemClick` after at runtime at a later point, after a bunch of ViewHolder's have been created, you would cause inconsistencies as the old ViewHolder's would be pointing at your old ItemClick.